# Wicket - Add column dynamically in wicket Table

Tags: java, html, json, listview, wicket

**HomePage.java**

```
Table table = new Table();

List<String> listOfString = (List<String>) table.getList(); //accessing list from Table.java
    System.out.println("listOfString" + listOfString); //List -[name, abc, id, 101, photo, true, name, pqr, id, 102, photo, true, name, bcd, id, 103, photo, false ]

    List<UserList> listOfBean = new ArrayList<UserList>();

    System.out.println("list of my Bean" + listOfBean);
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<listOfString.size()-1;i+=2)
    {
        
    UserBean mybean = new UserBean(listOfString.get(i), listOfString.get(i+1));     
    
    listOfBean.add(mybean);
    System.out.println("list of loop bean:" + listOfBean);
        }
        
    System.out.println("list of bean:" + listOfBean);

    add(new ListView<UserBean>("listview", listOfBean) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<UserBean> item) {
            UserList myBean1 = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", myBean1.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("id", myBean1.getId()));
        }
    });
```

**UserBean.java**

```
public class UserList {

private String name1;
private String type1;
private Boolean photo;

Table table = new Table("table");

List<String> list1 = (List<String>) table.getList();

public UserBean(String name1,String type1)
{
    super();
    
    this.name1 = name1;
    this.type1 = type1;
    
}

public UserBean(String name1,String type1,Boolean photo)
{
    super();
    
    this.name1 = name1;
    this.type1 = type1;
    this.setPhoto(photo);
}

public String getName1() {
    return name1;
}
public void setName1(String name1) {
    this.name1 = name1;
}
public String getType1() {
    return type1;
}
public void setType1(String type1) {
    this.type1 = type1;
}

public Boolean getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}

public void setPhoto(Boolean photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}   
}
```

**HomePage.html**

```
<table class="table">
<tr wicket:id="listview2">
<td><span wicket:id="name"></span></td>
<td><span wicket:id="id"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am accessing the List values in HomePage.java from Table.java(which converts json in the Database into a LIST).
However with the above code..I am able to successfully add the rows dynamically without changing the code but not the Columns dynamically.
Each time I need to define a constructor UserBean.java and instance in HomePage.java for adding column.

**Can anyone please suggest an alternative method of how to add Columns dynamically in ListView for display in Wicket Table.**

I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou in advance.

**EDIT-**

Table.java

```
String query="select row_to_json(t) from "
            + "(select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t))) as schema from (select name,type,photo from sample) t ) t";
    
    JsonToWidget widget=new JsonToWidget();
    JSONObject json=widget.getJsonForTableContent(query);
    json.toString();
    System.out.println(json);
    
    JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray();
    jsonarray.toString();
    
    Iterator<String> iter=json.keys();
    JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("schema");
    System.out.println("array"+array);
        
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        
        String key = iter.next();
        System.out.println("key:"+key);
        
        JSONArray value = json.getJSONArray(key);
        System.out.println("value"+value); // prints [{"name":"pqr","photo":false,"id":"101"},{"name":"bcd","photo":true,"id":"102"},{"name":"sadl","photo":false,"id":"103"},{"name":"123","photo":true,"id":"104"},{"name":"1234","photo":true,"id":"105"},{"name":"abc","photo":true,"id":"106"}]

        
        for(int i=0;i<value.length();i++)
        {
            Iterator it = value.getJSONObject(i).keys();
            
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                String k = (String) it.next();  //prints keys in json
                String v =  value.getJSONObject(i).get(k).toString(); //prints values in json
                
                list.add(k);
                list.add(v);
                
            }               
    }
        System.out.println("array list:"+list); //prints - [name, pqr,photo, false, name, bcd, photo, true, name, sadl, photo, false, name, 123, photo, true, name, 1234 , photo, true, name, abc, photo, true] 
}
}
 public List<String> getList()
 {
   return list;
       
   }
}
```

Is there any other approach of using JSON key-value pairs directly in add ListView(i.e read json in add ListView in HomePage.java) for display in Wicket Table **without using Beans and creating instances** so as to **add Columns and rows dynamically** from JSON from the Database.

Comment: You might want to check `DataTable` which is more suited for this. See: http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/repeater/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.repeater.DataTableFilterToolbarPage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read in your previous question, I think that you want to do something like this:

HomePage.html

```
<table class="table">
    <tr wicket:id="listview2">
        <td><span wicket:id="name"></span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="id"></span></td>
        <td><span wicket:id="hasPhoto"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

UserBean.java

```
public class UserBean {

private String name;
private String id;
private boolean hasPhoto;

public UserBean(String name, String id, boolean hasPhoto) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.hasPhoto = hasPhoto;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public boolean isHasPhoto() {
    return hasPhoto;
}

public void setHasPhoto(boolean hasPhoto) {
    this.hasPhoto = hasPhoto;
}
}
```

HomePage.java

```
Table table = new Table();

    List<String> listOfString = (List<String>) table.getList();

    List<UserBean> listOfUserBean = new ArrayList<UserBean>();

    for (int i = 1; i < listOfString.size(); i += 6) {

        UserBean userBean = new UserBean(listOfString.get(i),
                listOfString.get(i + 2), Boolean.parseBoolean(listOfString
                        .get(i + 4)));

        listOfUserBean.add(userBean);
    }

    add(new ListView<UserBean>("listview2", listOfUserBean) {
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<UserBean> item) {
            UserBean userBean = item.getModelObject();
            item.add(new Label("name", userBean.getName()));
            item.add(new Label("id", userBean.getId()));
            item.add(new Label("hasPhoto", String.valueOf(userBean
                    .isHasPhoto())));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thankyou soo much for explaining so well @ m.bouali... I have edited the question..Please refer once. Can you please suggest me an alternative approach..without using beans and adding rows and columns dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You need a more flexible data structure than a Java bean.

The simplest solution is to use `List<List<Object>>` instead. I.e. each element in the list would be another list. The first inner list would bring the columns' names. The rest elements would bring the cell values.

I hope you get the idea! Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou so much.... But Can you please explain programatically.... how to use inner lists as columns and rest as cell values in List<List<Object>> ?